# How to pass a function as a parameter in typescript functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a function and a number as parameters to a typescript functional component, I used the `any` keyword and there wasn't any error from the ide but when i ran the code, the error from the browser's console was the following. using javascript the code works as expected, please any idea how i can fix this error

```
react-dom.development.js:4054 Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
    at getListener (react-dom.development.js:4054:1)
    at accumulateSinglePhaseListeners (react-dom.development.js:9317:1)
    at extractEvents$4 (react-dom.development.js:8976:1)
    at extractEvents$5 (react-dom.development.js:9004:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9096:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:1)

Uncaught TypeError: handleDrawerToggle is not a function
```

```js
// Typescript
const App = () => {
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const drawerWidth = 240;
  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Sample
        handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
        drawerWidth={drawerWidth}
      />
      {mobileOpen && <h1>hello</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

const Sample = ( handleDrawerToggle:any, drawerWidth:any ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDrawerToggle} style={{ width: `${drawerWidth}` }}>
        Testv
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `handleDrawerToggle: () => void` would be the correct signature for a function that takes no parameters and does not return anything. Don't use `any` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing as `any`, you can be more specific and pass it as `() => void`. I would also advice to add a prop `type`.

For example, `type SampleProps = { handleDrawerToggle: () => void; drawerWidth: number }`

So something like

```
const Sample = ({ handleDrawerToggle, drawerWidth }: SampleProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDrawerToggle} style={{ width: `${drawerWidth}px` }}>
        Testv
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `{}` for the props of you component :

```
const Sample = ({ handleDrawerToggle, drawerWidth }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDrawerToggle} style={{ width: `${drawerWidth}` }}>
        Testv
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With your code handleDrawerToggle is like props if don't write the `{}` and props is an object.

Comment: with the curly bracket, it doesn't identify the any keyword and it gives more errors

Comment: See the other answer to use typescript